# Format number to not have decimals

Tags: php

Lets say the variable $number holds a decimal like 16.66677666777

How would I make it echo $number and just say 16 rather than 16.66677666777?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use inval function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

```
 $number = 16.66677666777;
 echo intval($number); //16
```

Answer (score 1):

This will suffice.

```
<?php
$number=16.66677666777;
echo (int)$number; //16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo intval(2.0000); //2
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 1):

Just use intval function

```
$number = 16.66677666777;

$number = intval($number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cast it to an integer:

```
echo (int) $number;
```

or using `intval`:

```
echo intval($number);
```

Or you could use the mathematic function `floor` to round the number down.

```
echo floor($number);
```

This function keep the variable type float.

Here you'll find a small example:
http://codepad.org/4um8gJSi

Answer (score 1):

you could also use floor()

```
echo floor(16.66677666777);
```